# Maxwell's Demon - Understanding Temperature change

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

In the typical Maxwell's demon scenario, there is a partition/barrier that the demon opens quickly to let a hot particle diffuse to the other side, thereby decreasing the temperature in one of the partitions and increasing it in the other. Is what is happening in this case that because the temperature has decreased, the entropy has decreased in that partition, hence, violating the 2nd law of TD?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem isn't that entropy decreased in the cooler side; we can also achieve this result simply by placing that side next to something even cooler. The problem is that (1) entropy decreased in the cooler side, (2) entropy increased by a smaller amount in the hotter side (following the relation $\Delta S=\Delta U/T$, where $\Delta S$ is the entropy change, $\Delta U$ is the energy change, and $T$ is the temperature), and (3) nothing else happens in the universe. This corresponds to a reliable global decrease in entropy, which the Second Law forbids. The explanation for this paradox is generally that (3) is incorrect; the demon must be associated with some increase in entropy (for example, destroying information) that at least balances the entropy books.

Comment: Thanks for that answer. Would this then imply where the entropy decreased in the cooler side, there would be some strange physics such as time reversal on the cooler side, i.e., reversal of arrow of time?

Comment: I've never heard that. Entropy decreases locally all the time: a condensing gas, a crystallizing liquid, a cooling object.

Answer (score 1):

Maxwell's demon would seem to violate the second law that states heat can not spontaneously transfer from a cold body to a hot body.

The temperature of each of the bodies is due to the average kinetic energy of the particles in each of the bodies, that average kinetic energy being greater in the higher temperature body than the lower temperature body. However, individual particles in each of the bodies can have a kinetic energy higher or lower than the average. There may be some particles in the lower temperature body with higher kinetic energy than the average kinetic energy of those particles in the higher temperature body. If the partition remained open (not controlled by Maxwell), some of those higher  kinetic energy particles in the lower temperature side of the partition can move to the higher temperature side, and vice versa. But on average, more higher energy particles move from the lower higher temperature side to the lower since the average is higher.

The demon, however, controls the partition to selectively only allows the fast particle in the lower temperature side to move to the higher temperature side, resulting in an increase in temperature of the higher side and decrease in the lower side in violation of the second law.

However, the second law applies under the condition that there are no external influences that transfer heat from low to  high temperature, like the external work that is needed to operate an air conditioner or heat pump. The demon is such an external influence. It can be argued that he/she does work to open and close the partition effectively allowing heat transfer from low to high temperature. I understand there are other arguments that deal with the relation between thermodynamics and information theory, the debate extending to the present day.

You can read about Maxwell's demon in Wikipedia.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

**1) What is entropy?**

Immagine two kind of particles, A and B, which have some property that is specific of its kind. Let's immagine that when many particles of the A species are close together they change some global property of the ensamble in such a way that the B particles can't. For example, A particles might have positive electric charge while B negative so that when many A particles are together they create an intense atraction for external negative charges, towards the box.

Immagine a box with two volumes separated by a wall. In one side of the box we put four A particles and in the other four B particles. Let's use this notation to show the state of the system:

[AAAA|BBBB]

In this situation the A particles are all together so they can perform "their magic" and create some clear global feature. In our example this would mean there's an intense electric field between both sides of the box.

Now let's suppose different state;

[ABBA|BABA]

Here the particles are the same, but their configuration doesn't allow for that electric field to be present between both sides of the box since in each side the number of negatively charged B particles equals the number of positively charged A particles, thus canceling each other out.

Now, how can entropy be understood in this context? Well ask yourself how many ways there could be a global net intense field from the right side of the box to the left side? Well there's just one. The one we saw previously: [AAAA|BBBB]. Now, how many ways we can produce no net field between both sides? Let's count:

[AABB|AABB], [AABB|ABAB], [AABB|BAAB], [AABB|BABA], [AABB|BBAA], [AABB|ABBA], [ABAB|AABB], [ABAB|ABAB], [ABAB|BAAB], [ABAB|BABA], [ABAB|BBAA], [ABAB|ABBA], [BAAB|AABB], [BAAB|ABAB], [BAAB|BAAB], [BAAB|BABA], [BAAB|BBAA], [BAAB|ABBA], [BABA|AABB], [BABA|ABAB], [BABA|BAAB], [BABA|BABA], [BABA|BBAA], [BABA|ABBA], [BBAA|AABB], [BBAA|ABAB], [BBAA|BAAB], [BBAA|BABA], [BBAA|BBAA], [BBAA|ABBA], [ABBA|AABB], [ABBA|ABAB], [ABBA|BAAB], [ABBA|BABA], [ABBA|BBAA] and [ABBA|ABBA]

Those are 36 different ways we can end up with a global net zero field. As you can see there are many more ways in which we end up with no field than ways were we have an intense field. Entropy is a way of counting just that; how many configurations there are where the global result of having no-field happens? That is the entropy of the no-field scenario. So if you compare the entropy of the intense field (which happens only in 1 configuration) with the entropy of no-field (which can happen with 36 different configurations of the system) you can clearly tell that the entropy of the no-field scenario is larger (a.k.a. there are more ways to generate that situation).

---

**2) Why entropy increases with time?**

This was just the definition of entropy but now we get to the Second law of thermodynamics which states that entropy increases with time. Why? Immagine we start with a low entropy state like [AAAA|BBBB]. Now we open a door in the wall and let the particles move randomly between sides for a brief period of time, until we suddenly close the door. What is the probability we still have some intense field (that we came back to [AAAA|BBBB] by random chance)? Well the probability is low. There are 70 different possible configurations and only one of them is [AAAA|BBBB], so this specific configuration has $1/70 = 1.4\%$ probability of happening after the door is opened. The truth is that every configuration has a $1.4\%$ probability of happening, but, since the no-field global state is reached in 36 different configurations, it means that the probability of having a no-field situation is $36/70 = 51.4%$. So you should expect a state of maximum entropy to be the most probable after the door opens, since you should expect the most common effect of different configurations to appear. It then follows that when the door opens we transition from an intense-field state to a less-intense field state much more probably, so the entropy increases with more probability than the possibility of a decrease.

Here we are talking about 8 particles but if we talk about a mole of them we are dealing with $\approx 10^{23}$ particles. In this scenario, the possibility that when the door opens the entire system sorts particles so that half $10^{23}$ positively charged particles go to one side and the other half of $10^{23}$ negatively charged particles goes to the other.... is not $1.4\%$ as before but is.... extremely low. It is almost inevitable that the entire system transitions with time to a higher entropy state, to a situation with no field (almost impossible to avoid this end result).

---

**3) What paradox does the Maxwell's Demon propose?**

In Maxwell's Demon we have an almost identical situation as before. A box with a wall partitioning the volum in two regions where particles of type A and particles of type B are trapped. The only difference is that instead of choosing the property of particles A being positively charged and B particles being negative, we choose A particles as fast moving particles and B particles as the slow ones. This is the microscopic property of each particle; velocity (just like the microscopic property stated before was the electric charge). The overall effect of the motion of particles is perceived as temperature (our macroscopi global feature was the net field generated by the charged particles in the previous examples). Everything happens in the same way, it is much more easy to have both sides of the box at the same temperature (filled with similar amounts of A and B particles) than having one side of the box filled with fast moving particles (high temperatures) and the other with slow moving ones (low temperatures). When you open the door in the separation it is statistically inevitable to end up balancing the temperature of both sides because there are miriads of many more ways to share the A and B particles homogeneously than having them sorted in a high-temperature-low-temperature sharp profile. The entire box will, with time, diminish the temperature gradient until both sides have the same temperature, if and only if the door is opened so the two kinds of particles can be exchanged between sides. This is what the second law of thermodynamics state for our model.

Now immagine a device that opens the door but only when a fast moving particle is coming to that opening from the left side of the box, closing immediately afterwards. Sucha device would have to be somehow intelligent, at least sensible, to know when that specific kind of particle would arrive to the door and to plan for its opening. With time this mechanism would be able to sort fast moving particles against slow moving ones; the A particles would accumulate in one side while the B particles would do so in the other side of the box. This means that this device would be able to rise the difference in temperature between the sides of the box. This is the Maxwell Demon. The apparent paradox is due to the fact the second law of thermodynamics would be violated, since the entropy would decrease (the end state would be an exceptionally improbable state).

The only way the second law of thermodynamics its preserved is if we assume that the mechanism (the demon), somehow created more entropy outside of the box while doing this work. But the question is how?

---

**4) Solving the paradox**

The solution to the paradox is a broad theme and very complicated to answer in a few lines but in essence it led to the understanding that information is a physical substance that also obeys the second law of thermodynamics. Information has a new kind of entropy defined to it, Shannon's entropy, and that entropy increases in the case of the Demon as it stores the information about what is going on inside the boxes or computes the program that allows him to plan for the correct opening of the door in the wall. The second law of thermodynamics is preserved but in the way we have to acknowledge the fact that entropy also expresses itslef in information, and that information is not an abstract concept but a physical entitiy that can be worked and reworked.

Answer (score -2):

Are you talking about demons? I think this is not the appropriate site for it!
Now, seriously. The demon needs an amount of energy to open the door. Just think about it. The total entropy of the demon and the gasses on both sides of the barrier has increased. Only when you assume demons can do that without being part of the system (as a good demon should), the entropy decreases.